# Do we need a Sociology tag?

Tags: discussion

Do we need a sociology tag?

I'm not sure how it fits into philosophy, and it seems to invite confusion that we do standard issue sociology questions.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I would say that sociology, as well as "social-ethics" (what is this, anyway? ethics shared by a group are ethics or morals) should be deleted and instead "philosophy-of-society" or something like that added, as this clearly refers to Lukács and the like, who were arguably philosophers and the Frankfurt School, where the institute is still named "Institute for Social Research".

Comment: I like this. I just wish we had more votes so that it's not just the oligarchs.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider sociology to have separated from philosophy the way psychology or anthropology have, then, no, we don't need a sociology tag. It also seems to invite a lot of current event and cultural studies questions, which when challenged, the OP says "But there's a sociology tag, why isn't this question valid?"